# Android Dependencies android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-appcompat

I updated my OSX and Eclipse and I got this error:

> The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/sagacity/Akii/Apps/android_alarm_clock/android-support-v7-appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: there is no solutions in eclipse?

Comment: Does the .jar file definitely exist in that location?  +1 for using Android Studio

Comment: @jcharlesworthuk Nops thats problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to add whole library as dependency instead of just the *.jar.

Comment: I already added android-support-v7-appcompat folder in workspace

Comment: try downloading again the support libraries from sdk manager..first remove then download. Then copy to your workspace and add as dependency.